# Facebook contest app, how to save user input, how to reuse app?

Tags: facebook, save

I'm working on a facebook contest application. How do you save users that entered the contest, can you also save their emails? I'm using PHP and hosting on heroku. If I want to reuse this app, how do you reset users?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you save users that entered the contest, can you also save their emails?

I'm not sure what you mean with this question, but you can request the user facebookId and email using the app permissions, then store those in a database;

> If I want to reuse this app, how do you reset users?

Do you mean to keep the same users and clean their stats? Have 2 sets of users?

If option 1, simply call a query to update the table and clear all relevant fields.

If option two, if you want to keep 2 sets of users, add a field in the user table called appInstance or something, then for each userbase you only load the ones that interest you.